# $f^2(x) \leq f(y)(f(y)+|x-y|)$ then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a function such that
$$(f(x))^{2}\leq f(y)(f(y)+|x-y|),\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Prove or disprove that $f$ is a bounded function.

---

One non-constant function I found satisfies the above property is $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$, which is a bounded function.

Such a function should be continuous since $$|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|,\quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$$ This can be seen by for example $$\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{|x-y|} \leq \dfrac{f(y)}{f(x)+f(y)}< 1.$$

Comment: Could you please provide more context/source of this problem and maybe a little more about what you have tried, if any?

Comment: Sorry, is $f^2(x)$ defined as $f(f(x))$ or $[f(x)]^2$?

Comment: @Tung $f^{2}(x)$ is $(f(x))^{2}$. I added. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following unbounded function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &  \text{ if } x < 1\\
\sqrt{x}& \text{ if } x\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
The assumption $f(x)^2 \le f(y)^2 + f(y)|x - y|$ is equivalent to

$$
\begin{cases}
x - y\le \sqrt{y}|x-y| & \text{if } x,y \ge 1 \\
0 \le |x - y| & \text{if }  x,y < 1\\
x \le 1 + |x-y|& \text{if } x \ge 1, y < 1\\
1 \le y + \sqrt{y}|x -y| &\text{if } x < 1, y \ge 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

The first case is true because $x - y \le |x - y| \le \sqrt{y}|x-y|$.  The second case is obviously true. The third case is true because $1 + |x - y| \ge 1 + x - y > x$, and the last case is true because $y \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank a lot for this answer.